What is the meaning of 'va' in the dialogue or utterance?
Previously, I did some research about this term, included using AI, but somehow i can't get it and simplify the explanation in one sentence. I found it in a story that I read. In the story this term is written as:
"You old rogue, va!"
Can you guys explain it in detail and serve the conclusion in one sentence?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A simple search in a search engine shows this sentence is from the English translation of a story by Guy de Maupassant: La ficelle (translated into English as The Piece of String). All this information should have been contained in the question, including the fact that the word vai s not translated (translator's choice). Your question just come down to what is the meaning of va in French, which question can easily be answered with the help of a dictionary.

Not being a telepath I cannot guess what intricacies you'd have me simplify; VTC for want of clarity. Could you please edit the result of your research into your question, in as many sentences as you like, no matter how clumsy the explanation looks to you? I'll gladly vote to reopen your question then.

@None To be fair it's not that easy to find a definition (in English) for this specific usage of "va". A French speaker could recognize it in a list of meanings but I wouldn't expect a non-speaker to find it easily.

The fact it is not translated is really bad. It's actually a mistake. You need to cite the source.

@Lambie While it's true the OP should have done it in the first place, None provided the source. Anyway, I wouldn't say it is a mistake. When translating foreign books, it is a common practice to leave here and there a few words deliberately untranslated as long as they are written in italics and their meaning is either likely to be known or at least understood by the readers.

@jlliagre I just looked at that translation. And there is no common practice when translating literature. A noun like macumba  might be left as in some translations of, say, a Jorge Amado, into English, but that emphatic va could have been rendered by many things. That va is not likely to be known as it is a quasi-interjection, spoken and very colloquial. Not the kind of thing one might learn in school when one harks back to one's school-boy (or girl) French.

@Lambie Too bad you are not aware of such a well established practice. Never mind.

@jlliagre Too bad you don't really know much about literary translation.

@Lambie You betcha! I don't know nothing.

Chill guys, i'm sorry for not giving a proper and complete information about my question. However, I'm really grateful for those who answer my question. And yes, this sentence comes from "The Piece of String" by Guy de Maupassant ([archiveorg oddnumber0000guyd width=560 height=384 frameborder=0 webkitallowfullscreen=true mozallowfullscreen=true]).

Why do i still not understand beside the dictionary said the point of the 'va' meaning? that's because the dictionary did not mention it in detail and there's two meaning of it an insult or colloquial interjection and 'go'. As a non-speaker of French, I'm confused, because i think this phrase could possibly have different meanings depend on the context of situation(?)

I choose to understand it as an insult, because it's the most relatable, but, what kind of insult? what words represent it? that's why i need the help of the native speaker in here. Because i need someone to give me more explanation than the dictionary did.

@NURKHAMIMAH Va used that way is not an insult. It is just a polysemic interjection whose meaning depends on the tone which it is pronounced, a kind of filler.

I see, noted, thanks for your kind explanation

"va" after an insult or a name-calling is just a way to add emphasis. The choice of translation is a little weird, I'm not sure what the translator aimed to do by keeping va in French in the English text, but I'd just translate it as "you" before the insult:

Imbécile, va!


You idiot!

It's a way to add flavor, for "exhortation, encouragement, threat or disdain" (see here). It's a little old-fashioned and not really in use anymore.

Yes, this is true but it would not be left in English.

@Lambie Yeah I really don't understand why the translator left it in

@TeleportingGoat: Possibly the translator thought "most English speakers can recognize that va means go," but somehow didn't notice that this usage of va doesn't really carry over to the English word go.

@PeterShor I don't think a perfect understanding is a requirement. From the context, a reader will at least guess it is some kind of interjection left here to "frenchify" the dialog.

I see... thanks for your answer, i do understand it now. I found the story from internet archive, this story is translated by Jonathan Sturges, if I'm not mistaken. The reason why he left some French terms probably to give the story an identity (setting, social, culture, etc)? I also didn't know why, but it's interesting to learn new things

@NURKHAMIMAH He might not have known how to translate it. One could do this for va: Come now, you old rogue. It's often used in response to previous speech, and can also express exasperation.

By the way, the translation on Gutenberg just leaves it out...

Alright, I'll try to look at it too later, thanks
